# Body of Async request in Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle

I want to send a asynchronous request using Guzzle PHP HTTP client, however it seems it only allows body to be a string .

I have header variable as

```
$headers = [
    "Authorization" : $token
];
```

Similarly I want to have body also as array

```
$body = [
    "x"=>$y,
    "y"=>$z,
]
```

I make a request variable as

```
$request = new  \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
    'POST',
    'API_URL',
    $headers,
    $body
 );
```

However I get `InvalidArgumentException Invalid resource type: array` error, but on trying `$body="some useless string"`, the request is sent to the server, but get error as body doesn't have appropriate parameters .

How can I set Body here as an array/(nested array if required) with my desired keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode` function, pass your body array by

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
    'POST',
    'API_URL',
    $headers,
    json_encode($body)
);
```